# Вывести последнюю запись по id

Tags: php, mysql

```
id|login|data
1 |test |data1
2 |test |data2
3 |test |data3

SELECT * FROM table group by login order by id desc
```

выводит

```
1|test|data1
```

как сделать что бы вывело именно последнию запись по id?
то сть `3|test|data3`
// логины могут быть разные

Answer (score 1):

Почитай про [HAVING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html)

```
SELECT login, data
FROM table
GROUP BY login
HAVING id = MAX(id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Хух. два дня рыл доки и разбирал примеры. Имеем тестовую таблицу:

```
id | login  | data
1  | login  | data1
2  | login  | data2
3  | login  | data3
4  | login2 | data4
5  | login3 | data5
6  | login2 | data6
7  | login2 | data7
8  | login3 | data8
9  | login4 | data9
10 | login4 | data10
11 | login4 | data11
12 | login5 | data12
13 | login5 | data13
14 | login5 | data14
```

Запрос:

```
SELECT 
  t1.id,
  t1.login,
  t1.`data`
FROM
  test t1
WHERE
  t1.id IN (SELECT MAX(t2.id) AS FIELD_1 FROM test t2 GROUP BY t2.login)
```

Результат:

```
id  login   data
3   login   data3
7   login2  data7
8   login3  data8
11  login4  data11
14  login5  data14
```

В WHERE так как подзапрос (SELECT MAX(t2.id)... возвращает не одно, а множество значений, используем предназначенный для этого оператор IN вместо = .
[Тут подробней про операторы сравнения](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Comparison_Operators.html)